# BitmapFactory wont decodeFile in 4.4.4 but will decode in 4.2.2

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

This code is called for during my `onActivityResult()` for my `Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

The specific line that causes the problem is
               `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);` near the end of the block returns null, and thus crashes when trying to pass bitmap to `bitmap = cropSquare(bitmap);`

It only crashes on 4.4.4 but works just fine on 4.2.2. bmoptions is initialized, and mCurrentPhotoPath is also.

```
                ImageView profilePhotoFld = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_photo);
                /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
                /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

                /* Get the size of the ImageView */
                int targetW = profilePhotoFld.getWidth();
                int targetH = profilePhotoFld.getHeight();

                /* Get the size of the image */
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
                int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
                int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

                /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
                int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);


                /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
                bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
                bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;



                /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,bmOptions);

                /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
                bitmap = cropSquare(bitmap);
                profilePhotoFld.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                itemPhoto = bitmap;
                itemPhoto = itemPhoto.createScaledBitmap(itemPhoto,640,640,false);
```

Comment: "Unfortunately, <APP_NAME> has stopped working." null pointer exception because i am passing null bitmap returned from `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` to `cropSquare()`

the sample photointentactivity provided at android developers website works just fine. i am debugging further now. 

it seems the `mCurrentPhotoPath` is vastly different in both apps.

Comment: ...and what is written in documentation of inJustDecodeBounds ?

Comment: in sample provided `mCurrentPhotoPath` equals `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraSample/IMG_20150312_105211_-1050594733.jpg`

in my app `mCurrentPhotoPath` equals `/data/data/<PACKAGE_NAME>/cache/IMG_20150312_105038_-421984001.jpg`

Comment: ok .... again: what is written in documentation of inJustDecodeBounds ? what will happend if it is set to true?

Comment: @Selvin I changed inJustDecodeBounds to false and it still returns null only in 4.4.4

Comment: Try to determine the file length. Is it 0 bytes? Try to let the picture save in external memory so you can see with other apps if it is ok. And add a check for null so you can display a toast an return instead of letting the app crash.

Comment: i figured it out. thanks guys! i rreally really appreciate it. will post answer below for other dumbasses such as myself.

Answer (score 0):

ok after extensively comparing my app to the sample app provided. my issue was *face palm* in my manifest file.

I had

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

and obviously was meant to use

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

thanks for those who spent time thinking about my issue. have a great day y'all

Comment: This can never have been the reason as /data/data/..... is internal memory for which you do not need that permission.

Comment: with this change it changes it to the same naming scheme provided by photointentsample, `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/CameraSample/IMG_20150312_105211_-1050594733.jpg` and it works. 

so for some reason Bitmapfactory.decodefile() would not take the internal memory path, and would return null for the decoded bitmap.